# Python Function if/else function

Tags: python-3.x

I am a student developer (day4) practicing some coding. I am looking for guidance on how to get this if/else function to work. the issue i am running into is getting the 2 list to work properly in the define function.

i am trying to get the code to compare the 2 list,

-if the names are in both lists print 'you are authorized'

-else if the name is in the list_name but not in the omaha_location,
print 'please see HR'

-else return 'you are not authorized'

```
def authorization(name):
  #if the user's name is in the list_names and omaha_location authorize 
`your text`if name.lower() in (omaha_location) and (list_names):`
     return(f"Hello {name} you are authorized")
  
  #if the user's name is in list_names but not in the omaha_location forward to HR
`your text`elif name.islower() in list_names not in omaha_location:
     `your text`return(f'{name}this is not your location, please see HR')
  
  #if the user's name is anything else decline authorization
`your text`else:
     `your text`return(f"Hello {name}, you are not authorized !")

name = input("Please enter your name:")
list_names = ['dan','kyle','lady','luna']
omaha_location = ['dan','kyle']
print(authorization(name))type here
```

i really appreciate your response. ive been at this for awhile.

I tried multiple methods. the code pasted is the closest i got to the desired results but its not quite there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stack overflow!
Your code has some errors in it, like the parentheses around `(omaha_location)` and `(list_names)`.
This should word for you:

```
def authorization(name):
    # if the user's name is in the list_names and omaha_location authorize 
    if name.lower() in list_names and name.lower() in omaha_location:
        return f"Hello {name}, you are authorized"
  
    # if the user's name is in list_names but not in the omaha_location forward to HR
    elif name.lower() in list_names and name.lower() not in omaha_location:
        return f"{name}, this is not your location, please see HR"
  
    # if the user's name is anything else decline authorization
    else:
        return f"Hello {name}, you are not authorized!"

name = input("Please enter your name:")
list_names = ['dan', 'kyle', 'lady', 'luna']
omaha_location = ['dan', 'kyle']
print(authorization(name))
```

Answer (score 1):

## There are multiple ways to achieve the same result (i.e any function). I'm giving the simple solution. Here the basic syntax.

```
    if name.lower() in [l.lower() for l in omaha_location] and name.lower() in [l.lower() for l in list_names]:
        return(f"Hello {name} you are authorized")
    elif name.lower() not in [l.lower() for l in omaha_location] and name.lower() in [l.lower() for l in list_names]:
        return(f'{name}this is not your location, please see HR')
    else:
        return(f"Hello {name}, you are not authorized !")
```

Comment: thank you for this. i will add this to my notes.